# Javascript object

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

```
function Person(fname, lname) {
 this.fname = fname,
 this.lname = lname,
 this.getName = function(){
 console.log(`${fname} ${lname}`)
 }
}
var x1 = new Person(“amnah”, “khatun”)
var x2 = new Person(“xyz”, “pqr”)
console.log(x1.getName())
```

output:

```
amnah khatun
undefined
```

I m only calling `x1.getName()` why both are getting called and o/p coming as undefined for 2nd one. How to fix this.
I have tried using protype property but that worked out either.

Comment: Because `getName` returns `undefined` and you're printing its return value with `console.log(x1.getName())`

Comment: use `return` instead of `console.log` in `getName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not returning anything from function `console.log(x1.getName())` will log the value returned from function which is `undefined`.

You should return the string instead of logging.

```js
function Person(fname, lname) {
 this.fname = fname,
 this.lname = lname,
 this.getName = function(){
  return `${fname} ${lname}`
 }
}
var x1 = new Person('amnah', 'khatun')
var x2 = new Person('xyz', 'pqr')
console.log(x1.getName())
```

Another point is that not logging the value of property you are turning the value from closure. It will `x1.getName` will always return same even if you change property.

```js
function Person(fname, lname) {
 this.fname = fname,
 this.lname = lname,
 this.getName = function(){
  return `${fname} ${lname}`
 }
}
var x1 = new Person('amnah', 'khatun')
x1.fname = 'changed';

console.log(x1.getName())
```

To fix this use this before properties.

```
 this.getName = function(){
  return `${this.fname} ${this.lname}`
 }
```

However this is not good to add methods to constructors. In this each and every instance of `Person` will have its own function `getName`. You should use `prototype`

```js
function Person(fname, lname) {
 this.fname = fname
 this.lname = lname
}
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
  return `${this.fname} ${this.lname}`;
}
var x1 = new Person('amnah', 'khatun')
var x2 = new Person('xyz', 'pqr')
console.log(x1.getName())
```